# TypeError: Parameter value is not iterable or distribution

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, matrix-factorization

I am new to Python and wanted to implement a simple Matrix Factorization Classifier.

As I read in another post, there are some possibilities which one can use and I chose `sklearn decomposition.NMF`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Parameter value is not iterable or distribution (key='n_components', value=2)
```

I was trying this:

```
self.clf = decomposition.NMF()                
    self.random_parameters = [
    {"n_components": 2, "init": None, "solver": 'cd', "beta_loss": 'frobenius', "tol": 0.0001, "max_iter": 200,"random_state": None, "alpha": 0.0, "l1_ratio": 0.0, "verbose": 0, "shuffle": False}
]
```

The interesting thing is, that I implemented the `RandomForestClassifier` from `Sklearn` before,and it works great:

```
self.clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()    
self.random_parameters = [
    {"n_estimators": stats.randint(20, 200), "criterion": ["gini"], "max_depth": stats.randint(1, 1500)},
    {"n_estimators": stats.randint(20, 200), "criterion": ["gini"], "max_depth": [None]}]
```

I also got this from the sklearn site: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

I was Googling for hours now and cannot find an appropriate solution unfortunately.

If somebody could help, I would be very grateful! Best wishes and stay healthy!

Comment: Reformatted code chunks and some grammar, indenting ,and new lines so the post is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

For **n_estimators**, Try passing a list of variable , I think it will work !

self.clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
self.random_parameters = [
{"n_estimators": **[20,50,100,200]**, "criterion": ["gini"], "max_depth": stats.randint(1, 1500)},
{"n_estimators": **[20,50,100,200]**, "criterion": ["gini"], "max_depth": [None]}]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

"n_components":[2]

Comment: Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your qnswer